# Why can't find element using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to find an element in [Yandex.ru](https://yandex.ru) through selenium and click on it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4ar.png)

the code is being processed but the click is not happening, I'm assuming selenium doesn't see the element.

```
def start_bot():
for i in req:
    browser.get('https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=65&text='+i)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-result"]/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]').click()
```

start_bot()

Referring to the parent class is not an option, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Assuming browser is already defined

try:
    max_delay = 10    # seconds
    browser.get('https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=65&text=1')
    button = WebDriverWait(browser, max_delay).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-result"]/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]'))
    )
    button.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timeout: Element not found or clickable')
```

Instead of waiting for a fixed `delay` (2 seconds) as you have done, this code will wait for the element specified by the XPath to be clickable. If the element is not clickable after `max_delay` (10 seconds), an error of type `TimeoutException` will be thrown.

You can easily adapt this code to open multiple urls in a loop (as you have done in your code).

**PS:** Please fix your code's formatting (the function call `start_bot()` is rendered as text, not code.)